# Knockout Binding has right count but text binding shows empty string

Tags: knockout.js

I am not a big JS or KO guy. I am trying to get paging working and have the paging part working. However when I go to bind to the text of each item to fill my table it is empty. I know the objects are there because I get the right row count and page count (3 rows per page for 8 pages as I have 24 objects). I have stepped through the code and verified the objects are there with the values. I am binding to a "page" field. When I drill into it I see the collection on the page._latestValue property (a collection of 3 objects). However, the following code gives me 3 rows with no values.

```
<div data-bind="with: pagedList">
   <table class="table table-striped table-hover tablesorter">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>FileName<span></span></th>
            <th>UploadDate<span></span></th>
            <th>LastAction<span></span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: page">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.description"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.fileuploaddate"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.lastupdated"></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Javscript

```
(function (Utils, ko) {
        Utils.PagedObservableArray = function (options) {
            options = options || {};
            if ($.isArray(options))
                options = { data: options };
            var
            //the complete data collection
            _allData = ko.observableArray(options.data || []),

            //the size of the pages to display
            _pageSize = ko.observable(options.pageSize || 10),

            //the index of the current page
            _pageIndex = ko.observable(0),

            //the current page data
            _page = ko.computed(function () {
                var pageSize = _pageSize(),
                    pageIndex = _pageIndex(),
                    startIndex = pageSize * pageIndex,
                    endIndex = pageSize * (pageIndex + 1);

                return _allData().slice(startIndex, endIndex);
            }, this),

            //the number of pages
            _pageCount = ko.computed(function () {
                return Math.ceil(_allData().length / _pageSize()) || 1;
            }),

            //move to the next page
            _nextPage = function () {
                if (_pageIndex() < (_pageCount() - 1))
                    _pageIndex(_pageIndex() + 1);
            },

            //move to the previous page
            _previousPage = function () {
                if (_pageIndex() > 0)
                    _pageIndex(_pageIndex() - 1);
            };

            //reset page index when page size changes
            _pageSize.subscribe(function () { _pageIndex(0); });
            _allData.subscribe(function () { _pageIndex(0); });

            //public members
            this.allData = _allData;
            this.pageSize = _pageSize;
            this.pageIndex = _pageIndex;
            this.page = _page;
            this.pageCount = _pageCount;
            this.nextPage = _nextPage;
            this.previousPage = _previousPage;
        };
    })(ko.utils, ko);
```

inside my ViewModel creation function I do this.

```
 this.pagedList = new ko.utils.PagedObservableArray({
            data: data,
            pageSize: 3
        });
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rX4Rn/ using your code.

I have added

```
var vm = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.pagedList = new ko.utils.PagedObservableArray({
        data: data,
        pageSize: 3
    });
    return self;
} 
ko.applyBindings(new vm(data));
```

And it appears to work.  We might need more details about the code to help any further.